# Inner join two tables with OR conditions

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to perform something like the following (which doesn't work):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `contestant_flags`
INNER JOIN
    `contestants` ON `contestants`.`id` = `contestant_flags`.`contestant_id`
INNER JOIN
    `teams` ON `teams`.`id` = `contestant_flags`.`team_id`
WHERE
    `contestant_flags`.`flag_id` = 1 AND `contestant_flags`.`call_id` IS NULL AND (`contestants`.`instance_id` = 13 OR `teams`.`instance_id` = 13)
```

I have a table, `contestant_flags`, where it can belong to either a single contestant or a team (`contestant_id` and `team_id`, respectively), but not both. The contestant and team each have a column, `instance_id`, which is what I'm attempting to filter by. So, for example, I may have some contestant_flags that belong to a contestant with the instance_id 13, and some that belong to a team with the instance_id 13, and I want to get the contestant_flags that meet either of those conditions.

The above query doesn't work, but given the explanation I'm after, can anyone help me out with a query that does? Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you try left join instead inner?

Comment: Please add sample data and your desired result to your question.

Comment: Why not make all contestants member of teams. So what if some teams have only one member

Comment: Did you want a count of rows from just the contestant_flags table, or did you want a count of the permutations, the number of rows returned from the JOIN operations?

Comment: @bksi Perfect, that was it. I had been staring at it so long I completely overlooked that little fact. I wish you would've made an answer instead of a comment so I could mark it for you.

Comment: No worries. The important thing is that you done the job :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make it left joins. And a coalesce looks a bit nicer if you know you one of them will always be null.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM contestant_flags
LEFT JOIN contestants ON contestants.id = contestant_flags.contestant_id
LEFT JOIN teams ON teams.id = contestant_flags.team_id
WHERE contestant_flags.flag_id = 1
AND contestant_flags.call_id IS NULL
AND COALESCE(contestants.instance_id, teams.instance_id) = 13;
```

Comment: +1. This works, as long as we are _guaranteed_ that `contestant_id` will be `NULL` when `team_id` is populated. Note that we could add predicates `AND contestants.instance_id = 13` and `AND teams.instance_id = 13)` to the `ON` clauses; with appropriate indexes available, that might improve performance a bit.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM contestant_flags cf
LEFT JOIN contestants c ON c.id = cf.contestant_id
LEFT JOIN teams t ON t.id = cf.team_id
WHERE
(cf.flag_id = 1) AND 
(cf.call_id IS NULL) AND 
(c.instance_id = 13 OR t.instance_id = 13)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to obtain the result (I think you are looking for)

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
  FROM `contestant_flags` f
  LEFT
  JOIN `contestants` c
       ON c.id = f.contestant_id
       AND c.instance_id = 13
  LEFT 
  JOIN `teams` t
       ON t.id = f.team_id
       AND t.instance_id = 13
 WHERE f.flag_id = 1
   AND f.call_id IS NULL
   AND ( c.id IS NOT NULL OR t.id IS NOT NULL )
```

To return rows when there are matching rows in either `teams` or `contestants`, but there's at least one matching row, you could use outer join operations to find matching rows, and then use a predicate in the WHERE clause to exclude rows that didn't have a match.

If `instance_id` is not unique in `contestants` and/or `teams`, this query could return a count larger than the number of rows matched in `contestant_flags`.

To count just the rows from `contesant_flags`, not counting any "duplicates" generated by the JOIN operations, you could replace `COUNT(*)` with `COUNT(DISTINCT f.id)`.  (I've assumed the table `contesant_flags` has a column named `id` which is guaranteed to be non-null and unique; replace `id` with any other non-null unique column (or expression) from `contestant_flags`.

In the more general case, to count just rows from `contestant_flags`, we could also use an EXISTS predicate.

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
  FROM `contestant_flags` f
 WHERE f.flag_id = 1
   AND f.call_id IS NULL
   AND (  EXISTS 
           ( SELECT 1
               FROM `contestants` c
              WHERE c.id = f.contestant_id
                AND c.instance_id = 13
           ) 
       OR EXISTS
            ( SELECT 1
                FROM `teams` t
               WHERE t.id = f.team_id
                 AND t.instance_id = 13
            )
       )
```